# touchesBegan method not called when i tap on UIImageView from multiple UIImageView display same as gallery in mobile

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitouch, touchesbegan

I want to touch on UIImageView and that image display in another view in full size using navigate the view. same as gallery in mobile.
just creating demo programmatically. because I'm new in iphone developing.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Enter in viewDidLoad method");

    UIScrollView * scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, self.view.frame.size.height+50);

    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [scroll setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    int x=5;
    int y=5;
    int hei=100;
    int wid=100;
    int k=1;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
        {
            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((x+wid)*i+5, (y+hei)*j+5, wid, hei)];
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Motocross.png"]];
            [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,(y+hei)*j+hei*2);
            [imageView setTag:k];
            [scroll addSubview:imageView];                        

            NSLog(@"The tag is == %d",k++);
            NSLog(@" (%d,%d)x == %d",i,j,(x+wid)*i+5);
            NSLog(@" (%d,%d)y == %d",i,j,(y+hei)*j+5);

        } 

    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"Exit from viewDidLoad method");
}
//Navigate on touch the imageView.
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    NSLog(@"Enter in touchesBeganWithEvent method");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == imageView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Enter in if condition of touch");
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController.imageD = imageView.image;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        [detailViewController release];

        NSLog(@"Exit from if condition of touch");
    }
    NSLog(@"Exit from touchesBeganWithEvent method");
}
```

I want to tap on imageView and view will navigate to detailViewController and display that image in big size. but this touchesBegan method not called when i tap on imageView. In this i'm not creating array of UIImageView just alloc init in loop.. Thank you!

Comment: is the touchesBegan method called? did you try inserting a breakpoint inside the method?

Comment: @i suppose your checking it incorrectly 
try this:
   if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `touchesBegan:` on the view, consider adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to each image view. When the image view is tapped (you are setting `userInteractionEnabled` already which is good) then you can get the view that was tapped with `sender.view`.

Note that you create a new instance of `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each image view that you have, but that the target/action of each gesture can be the same.

---

The problem with your current code is that this check:

```
if ([touch view] == imageView)
```

verifies the touch only against the last image view that you added to the scroll view. So, touching the last one should work, but all the others won't.

As per the comment from @vin, the correct solution to that issue is to verify the class type of the view that was touched:

```
if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
```

*(though the scroll view may have other image view subclasses than just the ones you add...)*

Comment: Thanks but i want to use touchesBegan method because i already told that I'm new in this and this is my demo project so i have to use those things  that  my sir want from me.

Comment: You should use the correct tool for the job, and that is a gesture recogniser attached to the target view

Comment: I know my friend but i can't postponed this topic to learn because I'm in training.

Comment: BUT my friend i can not even enter in this method (method not called when i tap please see the question.)

Comment: Try setting canCancelContentTouches of the scrollView to NO and delaysContentTouches to YES. The scroll view is eating the events (another reason to use a gesture...)

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code or its better to use Collection view

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Enter in viewDidLoad method");

    UIScrollView * scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, self.view.frame.size.height+50);

    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [scroll setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    int x=5;
    int y=5;
    int hei=100;
    int wid=100;
    int k=1;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
        {
            UIButton *buttonForImage=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((x+wid)*i+5, (y+hei)*j+5, wid, hei)];
            [buttonForImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Motocross.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [buttonForImage addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,(y+hei)*j+hei*2);
            [buttonForImage setTag:k];
            [scroll addSubview:buttonForImage];

            NSLog(@"The tag is == %d",k++);
            NSLog(@" (%d,%d)x == %d",i,j,(x+wid)*i+5);
            NSLog(@" (%d,%d)y == %d",i,j,(y+hei)*j+5);

        }

    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"Exit from viewDidLoad method");
}
//Navigate on touch the imageView.
-(void)imageButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender{

    NSLog(@"Enter in if condition of touch");
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.imageD = sender.imageView.image;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UICollectionview rather than trying to juggle with rows /colns, images touches etc...
Good tutorial is here... [UICollectionView Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)
(Assuming you dont support below iOS 6.0)

Comment: please see the above comments.